# ¿Cómo se pueden borrar datos duplicados de una tabla Backup?

Tags: sql-server

cuando creo un tabla backup a partir de una tabla ya creada, me da los resultados que quiero pero duplicados muchas veces. Cómo se podría solucionar ? Lo que hago es:

```
SELECT NOMBRE_JUGADOR, APELLIDO1, APELLIDO2, NOMBRE_LESION, FECHA_PARTIDO, LUGAR
INTO JUGADOR_BACKUP
FROM JUGADOR, LESION, PARTIDO
```

(Estoy copiando ciertos campos desde mi tabla jugador). Esto me mueve los campos que quiero pero me duplica los datos, unas 6 veces por registro.

Comment: Necesitas Limpiar la tabla al principio con: `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name` o esta ira acumulando datos.

Comment: 1. SQL Server tiene la capacidad de hacer backups _de verdad_ a un archivo o a cinta, sin tocar nada de la estructura de tu base de datos. Si por alguna razón quieres seguir haciéndolo dentro de la propia base de datos, por qué no haces una copia de cada una de las tablas por separado. Si  has normalizado para crear el modelo, ¿por qué perder esa normalización a la hora de hacer un backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La pregunta solicita como borrar datos duplicados, de una tabla de backup, aunque quizá lo correcto, sería que la inserción en la tabla no contuviera datos duplicados.

```
Create Table dbo.jugador_backup
             (
             nombre_jugador VarChar(100)
           , apellido1      VarChar(100)
           , apellido2      VarChar(100)
           , nombre_lesion  VarChar(100)
           , fecha_partido  VarChar(100)
           , lugar          VarChar(100)
             );
Go
Insert into dbo.jugador_backup (nombre_jugador
, apellido1, apellido2, nombre_lesion, fecha_partido, lugar)
Values
('jugador A', 'ape1', 'ape2', 'lesion 1', '2021-05-15', 'campo_A'),
('jugador A', 'ape1', 'ape2', 'lesion 1', '2021-05-15', 'campo_A'),
('jugador A', 'ape1', 'ape2', 'lesion 1', '2021-05-15', 'campo_A'),
('jugador A', 'ape1', 'ape2', 'lesion 1', '2021-05-15', 'campo_A'),
('jugador B', 'ape3', 'ape3', 'lesion 2', '2021-05-15', 'campo_A'),
('jugador B', 'ape3', 'ape3', 'lesion 2', '2021-05-15', 'campo_A'),
('jugador C', 'ape5', 'ape5', 'lesion 3', '2021-05-15', 'campo_A');
Go
```

Si el escenario de repetidos es el que se visualiza. Donde todas las columnas de la tabla tienen el mismo valor, para algunas filas, puedes aplicar la función de ventana row_number.

El elemento que determina, que filas son únicas, y por tanto se les asignará un rn=1, son las columnas que acompañan a partition by. Por tanto si hubiera dos fecha_partido diferentes para jugador_A, quedarían dos resultados para jugador_A.

```
;With c as (
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by nombre_jugador
                                          , apellido1
                                          , apellido2
                                          , nombre_lesion
                                          , fecha_partido
                                          , lugar 
                        order by nombre_jugador) as rn
From dbo.jugador_backup
)
Select * 
from c;
```

[image: Resultado]

Como puedes ver la columna rn, nos muestra las filas numeradas, por tanto para eliminar de la tabla, podríamos hacer un delete directamente desde la tabla de expresión común.

```
;With c as (
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by nombre_jugador
                                          , apellido1
                                          , apellido2
                                          , nombre_lesion
                                          , fecha_partido
                                          , lugar 
                        order by nombre_jugador) as rn
From dbo.jugador_backup
)
Delete from c
    where rn>1;
```

Lo cual nos dejaría como resultado 3 filas.

[image: Resultado]

[Numerar filas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)